# Single View, multiple ViewModels - avoid binding errors?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

There is a single View (window) with many controls, to simplify:

```
<!-- edit property A -->
<TextBlock Text="A" ... />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Config.A}" ... />
<Button Command={Binding DoSometingWitA} ... />

<!-- edit property B -->
<TextBox Text="{Binding Config.B}" ... />

<!-- edit property C -->
<ComboBox Text="{Binding Config.C}" ... />
```

This View is used to display and edit multiple configurations:

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BaseConfig Config {get {...} set {...}}
}

public class ConfigType1: BaseConfig { ... } // only has A
public class ConfigType2: BaseConfig { ... } // only has B
public class ConfigType3: BaseConfig { ... } // only has C
public class ConfigType4: BaseConfig { ... } // has A and B
public class ConfigType5: BaseConfig { ... } // has A and C
```

Properties **may** or **may not** exists for certain configuration. As a result there are binding errors.

Question: is there a way to hide controls which properties aren't present in current `Config` object (this could be easily done with reflection) as well as avoid having binding errors (and this is the actual problem, I don't want to re-invent `PropertyGrid` nor I want to use one) in the View?

E.g. if `Config = new ConfigType1()` (which has only `A` property), then View will only contains controls to edit property `A`, controls to edit property `B`, `C`, etc. should be hidden and do not cause binding errors.

---

Here is a test case if someone willing to play with it.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Config.A}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Config.B}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Content="..."
        Click="Button_Click" />
```

CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class BaseConfig { }

    public class ConfigA : BaseConfig
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConfigB : BaseConfig
    {
        public string B { get; set; }
    }

    public BaseConfig Config { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Config = new ConfigA() { A = "aaa" };
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Config = new ConfigB() { B = "bbb" };
        DataContext = null;
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Initially there is a binding error of missing `B`, after clicking button (`ConfigB` will be assigned) there is a binding error of missing `A`.

How to avoid those errors? Visibility can be controlled by checking with reflection if property exists (but there is still a question of how to organize that).

Comment: Are you adding properties to your configurations via reflection?

Comment: @tagaPdyk, nope. `ConfigType1` has only one property `A`, `ConfigType2` has only one property `B`, etc. (see comments in my code). Idea is to use same view where for each possible property there are controls with binding. And when configuration is changed no binding errors should occurs (and only those controls should be visible, which current `Config` has).

Comment: I would use DataTemplates per ConfigType.... if ConfigType1, render using A datatemplate, if ConfigType4, render using DataTemplate containing both A and B, etc

Comment: @Rachel, I'd also do that, but I don't want to duplicate the code. There are ~100 settings, they are split between ~20 configurations, same setting is used in more than one configurations. I am going to improve my answer by making behavior, which will be used instead of binding (to avoid naming elements in xaml and having code in the view). Maybe there is another way to do something with `Binding` itself? Instead of binding/unbinding use some of its mechanisms (if there is any) to disable it and to resolve binding errors myself. Is it possible?

Comment: You could make each item (A, B, C, etc) a template or user control, and then just have your Config data templates contain a ContentPresenter/Control for each one of your items... I don't think there would be any code duplication there. So them template for Config1 might be <ContentPresenter Template="{TemplateBinding A}" /> (or <local:ConfigAControl />) while Config4 would contain ContentPresenters/Controls for both A and B

Comment: @Rachel, yes, this should work. What I don't like with this approach is necessity to maintain manually 20 templates in addition to configs. Think about adding new property to some of configs. Therefore I'd really like to have just one *monstrous* view (100 different properties combined) but with **automatic** (write and forget) binding errors and visibility processing. The beauty of this approach is when you add a new config - it will just work from start (assuming properties which need to be edited are already exists in any other config)!

Comment: Well you could suppress binding warnings like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/124556/How-to-suppress-the-System-Windows-Data-Error-warn) but I really wouldn't recommend it as it could hide other problems as well. I suppose another possible solution would be to use an IValueConverter that uses reflection to determine if an object exists or not, and bind the DataContext or a ContentPresenter.Content based on that. Overall though, I personally would rather  use an implicit data template as described in some of the answers below :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is DataTemplate.

Working sample:

```
 public BaseConfig Config { get; set; }
```

```xml
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type o:ConfigA}">
        <!--
          You can add here any control you wish applicable to ConfigA.
          Say, a textbox can do.  
         -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type o:ConfigB}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type o:ConfigType10000000000}">
        <superComplicatedControl:UniqueControl ProprietaryProperty="{Binding CustomProperty}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--  Rachel's point  -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type o:Config4}">
        <StackPanel>
           <ContentControl Content="{Binding ConfigA}"/>
           <ContentControl Content="{Binding ConfigB}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
         <ContentControl Content="{Binding Config}" />
         <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="woosh" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Config = new ConfigB() { B = "bbb" };
    Config = new Config4() { ConfigA = (ConfigA) Config, ConfigB = new ConfigB { B = "bbb" } };
    DataContext = null;
    DataContext = this;
}

//…

// Rachel's point
public class Config4 : BaseConfig
{
    public string A4 { get; set; }

    public ConfigA ConfigA { get; set; }
    public ConfigB ConfigB { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but then `ConfigA` has to provide a list of properties, where different properties are packed into different types for data templates to work. Then I'll need some extra data passed (via attributes?) e.g. for name, for tooltip, for command? This all sounds like reinventing `PropertyGrid`, which is: more ugly (people do not like huge lists) and much more complicated than idea with single view.. if that idea is a good one.

Comment: Pardon me, but I can't relate on you zeroing in on PropertyGrid. Is it correct that your requirement is like a Multi-level Menu type of presentation where an Item may contain another Sub-Menuitems, and then another level, etc. etc? If I am correct, WPF has HierarchicalDataTemplate.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your options can be limiting if you only consider PropertyGrid alone. Perhaps Itemscontrol is a candidate to have a second look.

Comment: `PropertyGrid` = no. `HierarchicalDataTemplate` = no. `DataTemplate` = perhaps, but you have to explain how (I don't see an easy way myself, note: I may have comboboxes, buttons, etc to edit property, so it's not a simple `string`- or `int`-to-view datatemplating).

Comment: @Sinatr Sample code added.This is based on your code from your original question post.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the whole idea. What is a point in datatemplating when nothing is shared? It's way easier to make separate views (windows) to edit different configurations, don't you think? Notice `ConfigType5` (has `A` and `C`) in my question, when you put data template for it you going to repeat same code as for `ConfigType1` (has `A`). To make it more clear, for editing `A` you need combobox bound to dictionary of values and button to refresh it (via command), it's a nice bunch of controls (xaml) to copy-paste them for every config with `A`, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion tagaPdyk's answer is correct, but I think a sample can explain better how to do.

There is no need of reflection. The idea is to combine [implicit DataTemplates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w0x726c2(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [ContentPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Let's suppose we have to types of data: `Data1` and `Data2`. Here their code:

```
public class Data1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Data2
{
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Now I create a simple ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private Data1 data1 = new Data1();
    private Data2 data2 = new Data2();

    private object current;
    private RelayCommand switchCommand;

    public ViewModel1()
    {
        switchCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Switch());
        Current = data1;
    }

    public ICommand SwitchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return switchCommand;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Color> Colors
    {
        get
        {
            List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
            colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
            colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Yellow);
            colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);

            return colors;
        }
    }

    private void Switch()
    {
        if (Current is Data1)
        {
            Current = data2;
            return;
        }

        Current = data1;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return current;
        }
        set
        {
            if (current != value)
            {
                current = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Current");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `PropertyChangedBase` is a base implementation class of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Now the most important - for this question - part, i.e. the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="colors" Source="{Binding Path=Colors, Mode=OneTime}" />

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Data1}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" />

                <TextBlock Text="Description" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Data2}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="Alias" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Alias}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" />

                <TextBlock Text="Color" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ComboBox Text="{Binding Color}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colors}}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Current}" />
        <Button Content="Switch" Command="{Binding SwitchCommand}" Margin="30" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

As you can see I define a `DataTemplate` for each object I want to handle in the `ContentPresenter`. I have to set the `DataType` property for each `DataTemplate`. In this way the proper template will be automatically used inside the ContentPresenter (depending on the type of the object binded to its DataContext).

You can use the "Switch" button to switch between a `Data1` object and a `Data2` one. Moreover if you look at the Output Window of your VS, you will see no messages about binding errors.

I hope my sample can help with your issue.

**EDIT**

I placed the emphasis of my answer on the fact that with DataTemplates you have binding errors no more. There are not so many differences between objects with common properties and objects without them.

Anyway, let's suppose that both `Data1` and `Data2` derive from `BaseData` class. Here its simple code:

```
public class BaseData
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

In this way `IsValid` is a common property for `Data1` and `Data2`. Now you can choose between two possible solutions:

1. You add `IsValid` property to both the "implicit" DataTemplates.
2. You create a "base" DataTemplate (for `BaseData` objects) and the you reuse it in the "implicit" DataTemplates (pro: you have to write less XAML - cons: it can have an impact on the UI performance)

Regarding the second solution, your DataTemplates will become:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="colors" Source="{Binding Path=Colors, Mode=OneTime}" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type local:BaseData}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Is valid" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsValid}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Data1}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" />

            <TextBlock Text="Description" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" />

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource {x:Type local:BaseData}}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Data2}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Alias" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Alias}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" />

            <TextBlock Text="Color" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <ComboBox Text="{Binding Color}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colors}}" />

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource {x:Type local:BaseData}}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I don't see common properties for `Data1` and `Data2`. Please, check again question part where `ConfigType1`...`5` are defined. If configs have nothing in common, then I'd simply create different views (use different `UserControl`) and datatemplate them in parent window (`ContentControl`) to load needed view. This is easy. Hard part is this: there are ~100 settings, they are split between ~20 configurations (there is no rule, so I can't use inheritance to datatemplate base classes if that is possible) and I want to create **single** view without unnecessarily duplicating code.

Comment: Please @Sinatr, take a look to my edit, maybe it can be suitable for your problem.

Comment: I can't use inheritance (mentioned it explicitly in my comment). Next step will be to create base types for every property and pass list of such types to the View which will use datatemplates to display each type. And then congratulations - you have created your own `PropertyGrid`. Data-templates are limited: you can't manipulate them more than you can with the types, means - we can't have multiple base classes and we can't use interfaces for databinding as well. So while it feels promising this will lead to a dead end.

Comment: `DataTemplate` inheritance is an option (mentioned it explicitly in my answer), so you can use it or not, depending on your needs. In your comments you talked about `PropertyGrid` more than once, but you asked how to "avoid binding errors" and a possible answer is "just use DataTemplates". Maybe @Sinatr you should edit your question for explaining what do you mean with "PropertyGrids" and why you cannot/do not want to use them.

Comment: I did. See again `ConfigType1`...`5` part. It's mentioned - some of configs will have `A`. Some `B`. There is no inheritance. You gave me the answer, I appreciate your effort, but it's not helpful and I tried to explain why (I'll have to create datatemplates for 20 types and there will be a lot of duplicated code). Regarding `PropertyGrid`, it will work (because it can visualize anything with some effort put into editors and converters), but I don't want to use list-based control.

Comment: I see your point of view @Sinatr, but you should try making the same with other users. You ask for something and after a while you add new requirements... it is hard to understand what is suitable for you and what is not. Anyway, **I would like to know if you can consider using a DataTemplateSelector in your project**. I add just two quick notes: (1) if you have a lot of types, probably you have to write a lot of code independently on what programming language you are using. (2) `ContentPresenter` is not a "list-based" control.

Answer (score 0):

Working (but a crappy) solution is to use binding in code-behind:

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textA" />
<TextBox x:Name="textB" />
```

CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ...

    void SetBindings()
    {
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(textA);
        BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(textB);
        DataContext = null;
        Bind(textA, "A");
        Bind(textB, "B");
        DataContext = this;
    }

    void Bind(UIElement element, string name)
    {
        if (Config?.GetType().GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) != null)
        {
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Config." + name));
            element.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
            element.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Key here is to call `SetBindings()` whenever config is changed, which will first **unbind** (ignore `DataContext` manipulations, they are only here because of lacking proper ViewModel, make sure do not rise `Config` changed event until you unbind!) and then bind in code-behind with some reflection check to avoid binding to non-existing properties as well as control visibility.

I'll have to use this solution until better one comes.. if it ever comes.

Comment: This seems like solving one issue that will likely to sprout another don't you think? 1. Reflection will give us a performance hit. 2. Add another property to existing object? you need to modify binding in this code. 3. The more properties of different types, the more job you give to Bind() method - hence, maintainability?

Comment: (1) Binding uses reflection **anyway** (not all the time but to *establish* binding). I don't know by how much, but this going to be better than binding errors in any case. (2) Where did you spot added property? (3) Mentioned in the first sentence.

Answer (score -1):

To hide the controls you dont wnat to show you just need to bind the Visibility property (using a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to properties in your main view model.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Config.B}" Visibility="{Binding ShowConfigB, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

and in the ViewModel

```
public bool ShowConfigB
{
    get
    {
      return (Config.GetType() == typeof(ConfigType2));
    }
}
```

I don't think you can stop the binding errors with xaml only though. You could add or remove the bindings in code depending on the config class being used using BindingOperations.SetBinding and BindingOperations.ClearBinding.

Remember the users do not see the binding errors though. I'd only be worried about them if they were affecting performance for some reason.

Comment: This will still throw binding errors because there is control (another `TextBox`) bound to non-existing property `Config.A` (which doesn't exists). Visibility binding doesn't discard `Text` binding. I need an idea of how to avoid binding errors (and visibility).

Comment: What is your definition of a Binding error? where are you seeing them? Is your app crashing or is it just in the output window?

Comment: Going through the effort of making his view generic so it can work with all types of `Config`, and then using converters to check the concrete type seems to me like a step in the wrong direction. I mean, what's the point in a generic view when you still need to compare types?

Comment: Implementing something which throws binding exception and usage of converters where are not required will hit the performance of application.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the last statement is so wrong. Binding errors cause the most UI slowdown from my experience especially if they appears in some list controls. I'll have hundred of bindings in this view myself, don't want to experience that every time when switching to it. Moreover you should have 0 binding errors, because when you suddenly have one you want to see it. If you have binding errors all the time it's hard/impossible to spot new one.